# Magento extension working on local host but not working live

Tags: php, magento

facing problem with extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/coupons4u.html its working on local host but not working on live. in backend option is not showing.  problems are associated with case sensitivity but i don't know which code is case sensitive. 
I have installed extension,
I cleared my magento Cache,
Cleared all sessions,
Even flushed all cache from admin side.

But Still Getting Error of 404 while clicking on
Coupons => EinfochipsCoupons4U.

Please help me needfull

Comment: ,check your folder structure and the class name .

Comment: there are too many files and code . can u tell me right way which file i should check. when i am going to upload files via filezilla showing error Command: cd "/var/www/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/einfochips_coupons4u"
Error: Directory /var/www/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/einfochips_coupons4u: no such file or directory

Comment: just check the extension folders and classes.

Comment: in extension folders what should i check.

Comment: Admin folders and classes in the extension

Comment: i checked every files and edit problems  associated with case sensitivity. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

If the same module is working on Localhost but not after migration on live server, there is possibility of missing permissions i.e file permission is not proper after migration.I'll suggest to check permissions for all files in Module.

Comment: Give permission to all the files of the module "Coupons4U" from terminal.
like chmod 775 *; chown apache:apache *;

Comment: is there any solution.??